# How can I put anchor for email in PDF using itextpdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, anchor

I have to place some data in a table in a PDF, which has email information, it is required to put an anchor in the generated PDF, such that on click of that email, outlook window with pre-filled subject is opened and email can be sent directly by adding message to it.

Referring to online examples, I had put content to a Paragraph and added an Anchor to it, but unfortunately, it didn't work out, please find the snipped of the code.

---

```
    table.addCell(getLCell(1, labelMap.get("email"), 1, 8));
    Paragraph para=new Paragraph();
    para.add(new Phrase(email));
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor("mailto:"+email+"?subject=Reference Number:1234");
    anchor.setReference("mailto:"+email+"?subject=Reference Number:1234");
    para.add(anchor);
    table.addCell(this.getVCell(3, para, 1, 4));


private PdfPCell getLCell(int cspan, String name, int... d) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(name, normal_bold));
    cell.setRowspan(1);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP);
    cell.setColspan(cspan);
    for (int i : d) {
        cell.disableBorderSide(i);
    }
    return cell;
}



private PdfPCell getVCell(int cspan, Paragraph name, int... d) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(name.getContent(), normal));
    cell.setRowspan(1);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP);
    cell.setColspan(cspan);
    for (int i : d) {
        cell.disableBorderSide(i);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

---

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this must work...

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("sendMail");
anchor.setReference("mailto:"+email+"?subject=ReferenceNumber:1234");
para.add(anchor);
```

**EDIT** all depends of the final result you need. But this is working for me:

```
private static Font bigFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);

Paragraph para= new Paragraph("YOUR CONTENT", bigfont);

Anchor anchor = new Anchor("sendMail");
anchor.setReference("mailto:"+email+"?subject=ReferenceNumber:1234");
para.add(anchor);
```

Comment: I have already done that in the code, please have a look to the snippet attached

Comment: Check the edit... For me works... Which result are you obtaining? Maybe the `space` character in subject is the problem?

Comment: ultimately this anchor has to go in a table cell for the same, so the link is not working, please check the last method where the name.getContent() is used

Comment: Removing the space, doesn't work as well. The generated PDF doesn't even has that link in it.

Comment: You MUST use `PdfPCell` ?? Can't you simulate it only with a `Paragraph`?

Comment: that's what is used here PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(name.getContent(), normal));

Comment: I think problem is nesting `Paragraph` in `Phrase` and `Phrase`in `PdfPCell`. Why don't set the `Font` to the `Paragraph`?

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64795/discussion-between-jordi-castilla-and-d3x).